# MongoDB: How to add all appconsumption where appname have some five values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection of MongoDB. I want to add all appconsumption where appname have some five values.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493974"),
"appConsumptionDate" : ISODate("2017-05-28T18:30:00Z"),
"serialNumber" : "300000f10200a6e6c609",
"storeId" : "BST001690",
"created_on" : ISODate("2017-05-30T03:31:50.723Z"),
"isCldUploaded" : false,
"appUsage" : [
    {
        "appCatalog" : "empty",
        "appName" : "Google Contacts Sync",
        "appConsumption" : "27",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493979")
    },
    {
        "appCatalog" : "empty",
        "appName" : "Settings Storage",
        "appConsumption" : "94",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493978")
    },
    {
        "appCatalog" : "empty",
        "appName" : "Genie Suite",
        "appConsumption" : "9",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493977")
    },
    {
        "appCatalog" : "empty",
        "appName" : "Genie Registration",
        "appConsumption" : "98",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493976")
    },
    {
        "appCatalog" : "empty",
        "appName" : "Genie Ad Play",
        "appConsumption" : "13295",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ce7a62a83a3622d493975")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

I'm getting duplicates for the `storeId`.

Comment: i m getting duplicates for the storeId

Comment: can you please clear the meaning of "where appname have some five values."?